# Create a triangle on both top corners of Div, divided by borders

Tags: html, css

I was able to get a single triangle in the top right corner of my div by following this question and answer:
[Top Right triangle in Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531959/how-to-create-triangle-shape-in-the-top-right-angle-of-another-div-to-look-divid).

My question is how do I get another triangle in the top left as well? When I add code for the second triangle, my div comes out all messed up.

Here's what I tried.

```css
/*TopRight (if you comment out all .TopRightTriangle you will get the TopLeft working correctly)*/

.topRightTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.topRightTriangle::before,
.topRightTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.topRightTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.topRightTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: #000;
}


/*TopLeft (if you comment out all .TopLeftTriangle you will get the TopRight working correctly)*/

.TopLeftTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before,
.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="topRightTriangle topLeftTriangle"></div>
```

This is how the endDiv should look like

[image]

Comment: can you show what result should be?

Comment: @Duoxx Added the a picture to show.

Comment: because topRightTriangle topLeftTriangle is same element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about an easy way with **less of code** and linear-gradient:

```css
.element {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,  red 50%,transparent 50%) 100% 0/50px 50px,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, green 50%,transparent 50%) 0 0/50px 50px,
   
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, brown 50%,transparent 50%) 0 0/60px 60px,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,  pink 50%,transparent 50%) 100% 0/60px 60px,
  orange;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"> A </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe multiple before and after elements are not possible, so think you need to make an extra element overlaying. Sort of like this, but maybe it's not usable for your case? Hope it helps, sorry if it is not usable for you.

```css
/*TopRight*/

.topRightTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.topRightTriangle::before,
.topRightTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.topRightTriangle::before,
.topRightTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.topRightTriangle::after,
.topRightTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: #000;
}


/*TopLeft*/

.TopLeftTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before,
.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="topRightTriangle TopLeftTriangle"></div>
```

```css
/*TopRight*/

.topRightTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.topRightTriangle::before,
.topRightTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.topRightTriangle::before,
.topRightTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.topRightTriangle::after,
.topRightTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: #000;
}


/*TopLeft*/

.TopLeftTriangle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  position: relative;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before,
.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::before {
  border-width: 0.6em;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
}

.TopLeftTriangle::after {
  border-width: 0.5em;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="topRightTriangle"><span class="TopLeftTriangle"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this that you want?

```css
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.myDiv:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid gray;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid gray;
}

.myDiv:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid gray;
    border-right: 10px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It's missing the greyish border that is shown in the image at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Same effect slightly less CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="topRightTriangle"><div class="triangle-bg"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .topRightTriangle {
    width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.topRightTriangle:after, .topRightTriangle:before {
    content: '\25b2';
    font-size:20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    z-index:1;
}
.topRightTriangle:before {
    color:red;
    left: -4.5px;
    transform: rotate(97deg) skewX(33deg) skewY(-8deg) scale(1.2) translate(-1px,0px)
}
.topRightTriangle:after {
    color:black;
    right: -3.5px;
    transform: rotate(-97deg) skewX(-33deg) skewY(8deg) scale(1.2) translate(1px,0px)
}
.triangle-bg:before, .triangle-bg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border: transparent solid;
}
.triangle-bg:before {
    border-width: 0.6em;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    left:0;
}
.triangle-bg:after {
    right:0;
    border-width: 0.6em;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
}
```