# How do I make a div like this be able to expand to any size while having the corner triangles stay the same size?

Tags: html, css, image

As I said in the title, I want this div to be able to be any size, but without the corner triangles or the line on top getting bigger:

[image]

How could I achieve something like this with CSS?

Comment: easy way would be to take two triangle images and stick them to each side and let it size of the div get bigger or shorter flex you come handy in this respect or apply positioning if going CSS route.

Comment: have a look at this answer it covers your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518828/create-a-triangle-on-both-top-corners-of-div-divided-by-borders/49519034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an idea using clip-path:

```css
.box {
 /* adjust the variable to control the clip-path*/
 --b:10px;
 --c:8px;
 /**/

 border-top:10px solid #000;
 height:100px;
 background:#e0e5c1;
 clip-path:polygon(var(--b) 0,var(--b) var(--c),calc(100% - var(--b)) var(--c),calc(100% - var(--b)) 0,100% var(--c),100% 100%,0 100%,0 var(--c));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: That worked, though I have no idea how lol

Answer (score 1):

You may use gradients and padding.

possible example

```css
body {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left , #f8f3e0, silver, #f8f3e0, silver, #f8f3e0, silver, #f8f3e0, silver, #f8f3e0, silver ) ;
}

div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1.6em 0.5em 1em;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(140deg, transparent 1em, black 1.07em) 0     0 / 1.7em 1.45em no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 1em, black 1.07em) 100% 0 / 1.7em 1.45em no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 1.3em, black 1.3em 1.45em, #e0e5c1 1.45em);
}

div+div {
  width: 50vmin;
  float: left;
  filter:drop-shadow(0  0 1px crimson);
}

div+div+div {
  width: 30vmax;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 0px) drop-shadow(-1px 0px) drop-shadow(0 1px); /* a border ? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>Whatever comes inside</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>Whatever comes inside</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>Whatever comes inside</p>
</div>
```