# CSS-only corner badge

Tags: css, css-position

I want to display for some images a *corner badge* (the badge will be a FontAwesome icon).

The HTML layout is fixed, so I can't add/edit elements to it. I can only add a class programmatically to the parent `div` element...

The layout is this:

```
<div class="editor-choice">
  <a href="#" data-caption="">
    <img src="https://photographycourse.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Landscape-Photography-steps.jpg" alt="" width="650" />
  </a>
</div>
```

and the CSS that creates the *corner* is this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.editor-choice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}
.editor-choice::before,
.editor-choice::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  z-index: 1;
}
.editor-choice::after {
  border-width: 45px;
  border-top-color: rgba(250, 166, 28, 0.8);
  border-right-color: rgba(250, 166, 28, 0.8);
}
```

The problem is I can't display the *badge* part (a fa-diamond icon)... It will have to be a CSS-only solution in the form of an element relative to .editor-choice class, like:

```
.editor-choice img::after {
  content: "\f219";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

or something along those lines...

Any help will be much appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the before and after pseudo elements for your badge background, use only one, then use the other for the ICON rather than using the img/s pseudo element fopr the icon. Also I changed the z-index for the image to -1 and the ICON to 1.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.editor-choice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.editor-choice::after {  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 45px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: rgba(250, 166, 28, 0.8);
  border-right-color: rgba(250, 166, 28, 0.8);
}

.editor-choice::before {
  content: "\F219";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I had copied this CSS corner after a lot of search, trial and error (I'm not a front-end dev, I do back-end mostly) a lot of time ago, and TBH I had found it somewhere on this site if I recall... So I had the impression that the ::before was also needed (both were used there)... Indeed however, ::before isn't necessary, I wonder how I hadn't figured this out earlier! Of course, now that I saved ::before pseudo-element, I can perfectly use it for the fa-diamond icon! Thanks a LOT for this!

EDIT: This is the resource 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18532104/15576971

Comment: Glad it helped out. ;)