# Slanted div css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a slanted sidebar menu to my website like in the wider shape picture attached. The idea is to start the diagonal lines in both the top and bottom of the div from about the middle of the width, maybe even from a bit closer to the edges. Eventually when the menu is collapsed, it suppose to look like in the picture with the narrow shape. How can I do it? Thanks!
P.S: I already got the functionality to work. I only need help with the CSS Design of the div.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create triangle shape in the top-right angle of another div to look divided by border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531959/how-to-create-triangle-shape-in-the-top-right-angle-of-another-div-to-look-divid)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.triangle-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 750px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 750px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-left">
  
</div>
```

This can probably be adjusted as well for your needs but this is how I went about attempting this.